# How find repeating pairs in different groups in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have data in a MySQL table:

```
+-----+----+-------------+
| id  | n1 | n2          |
+-----+----+-------------+
|  1  |  A |  1111111111 |
|  2  |  A |  2222222222 |
|  3  |  B |  1111111111 |
|  4  |  C |  1111111111 |
|  5  |  C |  4444444444 |
|  6  |  C |  3333333333 |
|  7  |  B |  2222222222 |
|  8  |  B |  3333333333 |
|  9  |  D |  2222222222 |
|  10 |  D |  4444444444 |
|  11 |  D |  1111111111 |
+-----+----+-------------+
```

Need check of there values in "n2" from one group "n1" same to other group in "n1". If so, arrange them and calculate:

```
+-----+----+-------------+
| id  | n1 | n2          |
+-----+----+-------------+
|  1  |  A |  1111111111 |
|  2  |  A |  2222222222 |
|  3  |  B |  1111111111 |
|  7  |  B |  2222222222 |
|  9  |  D |  2222222222 |
|  11 |  D |  1111111111 |

|  3  |  B |  1111111111 |
|  8  |  B |  3333333333 |
|  4  |  C |  1111111111 |
|  6  |  C |  3333333333 |

|  4  |  C |  1111111111 |
|  5  |  C |  4444444444 |
|  11 |  D |  1111111111 |
|  10 |  D |  4444444444 |
+-----+----+-------------+
```

1111111111/2222222222 - 3 times in "n1" A,B,D
1111111111/3333333333 - 2 times in "n1" B,C
1111111111/4444444444 - 2 times in "n1" C,D

Please help how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want a `GROUP BY` with `HAVING COUNT(n2) > 1`.

```sql
SELECT n1, n2, COUNT(n2) as cnt
FROM table
GROUP BY n2, n1
HAVING COUNT(n2) > 1
```